# Hadoop hdfs to elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs, kibana

How do I read data from HDFS and then send them to Elasticsearch and display on kibana dashboard?

I know there is a connector in ES-Hadoop which works bidirectionally to to send data out/receive, but my question is in the first stage Pulling data from HDFS

What are the most feasible options? Please provide me with couple of options..

Helpful information: I have a Hadoop HDFS system that is summarizing the logs... so i have to get those logs onto elastic search and display it on the Kibana dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly create a bash script that runs periodically and calls

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal <src> <dest>
```

to copy all your data from hdfs.

Or create an input stream using Hadoop's FileSystem java api to stream the data from hadoop:

```
public static FileSystem getFS(String hadoopUser) { 
    UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation
                .createRemoteUser(hadoopUser);

    return ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedAction<FileSystem>() {

        @Override
        public FileSystem run() {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            try {
                return FileSystem.get(conf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

And then...

```
FileSystem fs = getFS("hdfs");

InputStream in = fs.open(new Path("/path/to/hdfs/file"));

//do stuff with your input stream here...
```

Regarding getting that data onto elasticsearch, you could do something similar to what Netflix does with inviso (search up inviso in github and look at jes/index_cluster_stats.py to get an idea). Basically, write a python script that integrates with elasticsearch and have this script run every few minutes to parse the data you pulled from HDFS and subsequently store that data in elasticsearch.